# Why is there no NA_logical_

Tags: r, missing-data

From `help("NA")`:

> There are also constants NA_integer_, NA_real_, NA_complex_ and
>   NA_character_ of the other atomic vector types which support missing
>   values: all of these are reserved words in the R language.

My question is why there is no `NA_logical_` or similar, and what to do about it.

Specifically, I am creating several large very similar `data.table`s, which should be class compatible for later `rbind`ing.  When one of the `data.table`s is missing a variable, I am creating that column but with it set to all `NA`s of the particular type.  However, for a logical I can't do that.

In this case, it probably doesn't matter too much (`data.table` dislikes coercing columns from one type to another, but it also dislikes adding rows, so I have to create a new table to hold the rbound version anyway), but I'm puzzled as to why the `NA_logical_`, which logically should exist, does not.

Example:

```
library(data.table)
Y <- data.table( a=NA_character_, b=rep(NA_integer_,5) )
Y[ 3, b:=FALSE ]
Y[ 2, a:="zebra" ]
> Y
       a  b
1:    NA NA
2: zebra NA
3:    NA  0
4:    NA NA
5:    NA NA
> class(Y$b)
[1] "integer"
```

Two questions:

1. Why doesn't `NA_logical_` exist, when its relatives do?
2. What should I do about it in the context of `data.table` or just to avoid coercion as much as possible? I assume using `NA_integer_` buys me little in terms of coercion (it will coerce the logical I'm adding in to 0L/1L, which isn't terrible, but isn't ideal.

Comment: I can't resist referring to thedailywtf.com, where people regularly explain that a `logical` has the possible values "TRUE, FALSE, File_Not_Found" .  Edit- This would have been funnier if Dirk E hadn't pointed out that `R` actually does this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`NA` is already logical so `NA_logical_` is not needed.  Just use `NA` in those situations where you need a missing logical.  Note:

```
> typeof(NA)
[1] "logical"
```

Since the `NA_*_` names are all reserved words there was likely a desire to minimize the number of them.

Example:

```
library(data.table)
X <- data.table( a=NA_character_, b=rep(NA,5) )
X[ 3, b:=FALSE ]
> X
    a     b
1: NA    NA
2: NA    NA
3: NA FALSE
4: NA    NA
5: NA    NA
```

Comment: Ah, that makes much sense!  Could they add a variable `NA_logical_` which pointed to the reserved word by default, rather like how `T` poitns to `TRUE`?

Comment: If you really must have it then its possible to define it yourself:  `NA_logical_` <- NA`

Comment: Sure, but then I would never used it because I'd be afraid it would fail on a new computer.  Now that I know, `NA` is clearly the way to go.  Just an interesting quirk.

Comment: It occurs to me that it makes total sense that `NA` is the logical version, since then it can be coerced "up" to anything else.

Answer (score 4):

I think based on this

```
 #define NA_LOGICAL R_NaInt
```

from `$R_HOME/R/include/R_ext/Arith.h` we can suggest using `NA_integer` or `NA_real` and hence plain old `NA` in R code:

```
R> as.logical(c(0,1,NA))
[1] FALSE  TRUE    NA
R> 
R> as.logical(c(0L, 1L, NA_integer_))
[1] FALSE  TRUE    NA
R>
```

which has

```
R> class(as.logical(c(0,1,NA)))
[1] "logical"
R> 
R> class(as.logical(c(0, 1, NA_real_)))
[1] "logical"
R>
```

Or am I misunderstanding your question?  R's logical type is three-values: yay, nay and missing. And we can use the NA from either integer or numeric to cast.  Does that help?